# Electron Builder cannot move downloaded into final location (another process downloaded faster?) error=rename

Tags: npm, electron, electron-builder

"electron-builder": "^20.38.5"

Not using electron updater
Target: Windows
Running electron builder on windows 10 Home

build process cannot package and presents this error
cannot move downloaded into final location (another process downloaded faster?) error=rename C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\105845327 C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\winCodeSign-2.4.0: Access is denied. path=C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\winCodeSign-2.4.0 tempFile=C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\105845327

I have tried to run the process with an administrative window, but still presents the error.
I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable your antivirus. It is blocking the builder from copying the required files. Worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Just rename the temp folder to the name of the destination folder (in your example `C:\Users\Developer\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\winCodeSign\winCodeSign-2.4.0`).

Answer (score 2):

Same situation for me but with winCodeSign-2.6.0.
Due to company restriction, I could not disable the antivirus.
So, the workaround suggested by @Avin Shum works: rename the temporary folder inside winCodeSign folder name from
**14617003** to **WinCodeSign-2.6.0**

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a problem with the "nsis" folder. I just needed to rename exactly as the command was trying to do but access was denied:

> error=rename C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\196512019 C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\electron-builder\Cache\nsis\nsis-3.0.4.1: Access is denied.

So I manually renamed the cached folder "196512019" (it should be different each time you run) to "nsis-3.0.4.1" and it did the job.